How to format decimal value using left and right padding in jolt?
I want to format a decimal input such that I get a specific number of characters in the output, 10 digits before the decimal point and 4 digits after the decimal point. I want to pad with 0 values. Also if the input is null, then the output should be 0s with the given padding.
For example, if I take the following input:
[
  {
    "field1": "875.45",
    "field2": ""

  }
]

Then the output should be:
[
  {
    "field1": "0000000875.4500",
    "field2": "0000000000.0000"
  }
]


Welcome to SO Deshna

You can use modify-overwrite-beta transformation spec along with [left/right]Pad functions such as
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "pieces": "=split('\\.',@(1,field1))",//separate expression by dot 
        //by using escape( \\ ) characters, since some characters are onsidered 
        //as special such as dot         
        "piece1": "=leftPad(@(1,pieces[0]), 10, '0')",
        "piece2": "=rightPad(@(1,pieces[1]), 4, '0')",
        "field1": "=concat(@(1,piece1),'.',@(1,piece2))"
      }
    }
  },
  {// get rid of the unnecessary attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "piece*": ""
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

